# Spring data neo4j - polymorphic children collection

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have following classes:

```
public interface Label {
  String getValue();
}

@Node
@Data
public class SimpleLabel implements Label {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String value;

  @Relationship(value = "JE")
  private Set<SimpleLabel> labels = new HashSet<>();

  public void addLabel(SimpleLabel label){
    labels.add(label);
  }
}

@Node
@Data
public class HyperLabel implements Label {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Relationship(value = "JE")
  private Set<Label> labels = new HashSet<>();

  public void addLabel(Label label){
    labels.add(label);
  }

  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return labels.stream().map(Label::getValue).collect(Collectors.joining("; "));
  }
}
```

and this is the query I'm using:

```
  @Query("MATCH (h:HyperLabel)-[r:JE]-(s:SimpleLabel) WHERE ID(h)=$id RETURN h,COLLECT(r),COLLECT(s)")
  Optional<HyperLabel> getById(Long id);
```

The problem, I'm having is that `labels` collection that is returned by query is empty. But if I make a slight change in the code of `HyperLabel` class (change `Set<Label>` to `Set<SimpleLabel>`), then it works.

Is there any way to make it work with `Label` interface, since children of `HyperLabel` can be both `HyperLabel` and `SimpleLabel` instances?

Comment: I think you just found https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2290 does this behavior improve if you change the name of the property in one of those classes?

Comment: @meistermeier you mean to differentiate it based on a property? `HyperLabel` does not have `value` property inside. What would I get by changing property name?

Comment: They both have labels defined. Renaming one to something else should work.